# Get data from span element with data-* attribute(HtmlUnit)

Tags: java, html, jquery, get, htmlunit

I'm in the process of developing a webscraper and one of the problems i've ran into is getting data from a clickable span element that fetches data from the server according to the 'data-id' attribute on a click event. Here's how it looks on the website:

```html
<td class="field">
  <span class="value">
   <span class="preview">Data Preview...</span>
   <span class="span-trigger" data-id="a51a42a4811cb9b6908e5">Show</span>
  </span>
</td>
```

The state it takes after clicking on the span:

```
<td class="field value">Data</td>
```

I've captured all of the 'data-id' attributes with the webscraper but now i'm wondering whether it would be possible to automate the requests that change the 'data-id' and get the data behind the click events with HTMLUnit.

Comment: What's your question? How to trigger a click programmatically?

Comment: No. Triggering a click isn't the answer since the "span-trigger" element gets removed on the click event. I'm wondering whether it would be possible to construct some sort of GET request that takes the 'data-id' as a parameter and gets the data linked to the id as a response.

Comment: Of course it's possible. But how are we supposed to help you not knowing anything about the GET request, the API or anything else here?

Comment: I'm rather new to developing these kinds of things in general so excuse my greenery on this matter. As of right now I'm unsure what more to provide since this is all that is pretty much all that I'm faced with. There is a span element on a webpage that I need to request with a modified attribute using HTMLUnit.

Comment: What you need to provide for us to help you is a re-producible example of the issue. Right now you're asking how to make an API call. That's way to broad and linkely not what you're looking for. What is the call you want to make specifically? What is the HTML want to iterate? All we have is a span. Imagine being the one who is asked. You've also tagged this with `java` and `jquery` which is confusing. What stack are you using?

Comment: I've edited the original question as best  I can. Don't have anything more to provide.

Comment: You would need to reverse engineer such requests by seeing what requests get made in browser dev tools network when you interact with those elements. There is no way to know by just looking at the html. Trying to do such reverse engineering can be very time consuming in many cases and not trivial

Comment: Any tips or material on how to go about doing that?